# Select data from multiple tables and compare different columns

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I select data from two different tables and compare them and get the result ?

I have a table1

```
id  name    surname    adress
1   Fred    Lapinski   brook st. 3-5
2   Albert  Enstein    wall st. 3-5
3   David   Leterman   blue st. 3-5
4   Andrew  Igudola    groov st. 3-5
```

And Table2

```
id  name             replacement
1   Patrick Kane     Igor Petrov
2   Fred Lapinski    Warrent Buffet
3   Sabrina Kubrick  Bill Dill
4   Andrew Igudola   Rebbeca Aberson
```

I want to select data from both tables and if the name from table1 is the same as name from table2 echo true and echo the name of replacement. 
I am making a system what shows who of the worker is not at the work today and who is replacing it.

Comment: Do you only want rows where the `name` in table 1 is equal to the `name` in table 2?

Comment: I need to get a value what can I put in if so I cant determine who is away and who is not and if the employee is away I cant display replacement. Its a bit complex and sorry for my English, it is not my native.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```sql
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN t2.id IS NOT NULL THEN 'T' ELSE 'F' END AS name_match, 
  COALESCE(
    t2.replacement, -- Return "replacement" if exists
    CONCAT(t1.name,' ', t1.surname) -- Otherwise return original name
  ) AS name_final
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON (CONCAT(t1.name, ' ', t1.surname)) = t2.name
```

This assumes a name match means `<name> <surname>` in `table1` = `<name>` in `table2`

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
table2.name, replacement 
from 
(select CONCAT(name, ' ', surname) as name from table1) a, table2
where 
a.name = table2.name;
```

table1 contains name and surname in two different columns whereas table2 contains full name in one column only. If we need to compare names of table1 and table2, then we need to concatenate first name and last name of table1 and then it should be joined with name of table2.

Comment: Can you please explain your code, so others can learn from it

Comment: table1 contains name and surname in two different columns whereas table2 contains full name in one column only. If we need to compare names of table1 and table2, then we need to concatenate first name and last name of table1 and then it should be joined with name of table2.